# write to a mailbox of other node directly using socket in python

Tags: python, sockets

i have two node that connect together using socket in python.
i want to have a mailbox (or buffer) on each node. How node A can write to mailbox of node B directly (without interference of node B) using socket and vise versa?

Comment: can you explain yourself? the question isn't clear,anyhow when you send data using a socket you don't interrupt the function of the other side

Comment: Please provide more details. Are the nodes on the same computer, or on the same network?

Comment: i want to  don't interrupt (block) other node with socket when writing to its mailbox, and node are the network. the problem is to address mailboxes!

Comment: @user3098838 what do you mean by "the problem is to address mailboxes" ? if you don't want to block the other node by calling `sock.read()` you can use a thread or the syscall select or using a non-blocking socket

Comment: about non-blocking socket : maybe node A sometimes don't have any message to node B, is this a problem for non-blocking socket ? (the relation of two node is bidirectional and each node has other cpu-bound computation)

Comment: @user3098838 well yes and no,yes it wouldn't be a problem but it will exhaust the CPU for nothing.you can also delegate the receive to another thread and use some sort of signaling,this way you can have one thread doing some thing and the other thread will block it receive a message and signals the first thread that can handle the data. you can also use a timeout on a blocking socket

Comment: thanks omer12433 for your help, my problem is that i shouldn't use Thread . . . and when i want to use a simple mailbox i don't know how to access to mailbox of other node!

Comment: @user3098838 ok then you only options are a non blocking socket or a blocking socket with a timeout value

Comment: can give me a link about non-blocking socket? i am new in socket programming.

Comment: @user3098838 use google seriously just search something like "python socket non blocking example "

Comment: really thanks omer12433.